# OpenCV - Verify Essential Matrix by Rotation and Translation (decomposeEssentialMat function)

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

I am trying to verify that the procedure I followed is correct.

I extracted the rotation matrices R1 and R2 and the translation vector T from the function: decomposeEssentialMat(essentialMatrix, R1, R2, t)

My theory is that I can then use R1 or R2 multiplied with Tx to get the essential matrix again by E = Tx*R

Hence I construct a skewed 3x3 matrix for Tx:

```
Tx = [ 0    -t(3)  t(2)
       t(3)  0    -t(1)
      -t(2)  t(1)   0 ]
```

Followed by multiplying it with either R1 or R2. The result is nowhere close to the essential matrix I originally decomposed.

**The procedure:**
I compute the essential matrix from my fundamental matrix and camera calibrations. Since I use only one camera, the same parameters are inserted for refCam and auxCam (Cam1 and Cam2)
[Camera Calibration Parameters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwC7p.png)

The essential matrix is then computed by: EssentialMatrix = refCamMat.t() * fundamental * auxCamMat;

Moving further I decompose the essentialMatrix by: decomposeEssentialMat(essentialMatrix, R1, R2, t)

I get R1 and R2 and 3x3 matrices, and t and 3x1 vector. I transform vector to skewed 3x3 matrix as follows:

```
Tx = [ 0    -t(3)  t(2)
       t(3)  0    -t(1)
      -t(2)  t(1)   0 ]
```

I then perform simple matrix multiplication by Tx * R1 or Tx * R2

Yielding:

[Input EssentialMatrix, R1, R2, t, Tx, Output EssentialMatrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8yeV.png)

Clearly the output essential matrix does not match the input essential matrix. Also not with any scaling.

Any guidance? :/

I tried transposing and taking the inverse

Comment: Isnt  `E=R*T`, so you would have to switch from `Tx * R1 or Tx * R2` to `R1 * Tx or R2 * Tx`? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix . In addition, `the translation t is returned with unit length` according to https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga54a2f5b3f8aeaf6c76d4a31dece85d5d

Comment: I did some more digging on this. Neither of your matrices are valid essential matrices. An essential matrix must have an SVD with two equal singular values and a third which is zero. neither of your matrices satisfies this property, though of course, the decomposed matrices do. How are you constructing the matrices?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_matrix#:~:text=Not-,every,-arbitrary